# The storage system passwords

Tags: python, encryption, passwords, storage

At work we are doing monitoring system servers. We have passwords that give access to the servers. Kept it all should in the database. We will be held on the basis of encrypted passwords, and must connect to servers using the decrypted passwords.

> The problem - where to store the decryption key password? Which is
>   better to use an encryption method?  Do commercial ready \ open
>   solutions for this?

All this is done on a bunch Python + Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such frameworks had to write everything yourself.